# Link Elements in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good Day!

I have a subset of a pandas DataFrame "mapSubset" with non-continuous indices due to filtering. The DataFrame contains 'key' values.

> ```
> mapSubset
>    val  key
> 0   12    0
> 2   18    1
> 4   24    2
> 6   30    3
> 8   36    4
> ```

In the pandas DataFrame "link", which contains 'key' values corresponding to the 'key' values in the "mapSubset" DataFrame, I want to add the corresponding indices from the "mapSubset"
(DataFrame).

> ```
> link
>    key
> 0    4
> 1    2
> 2    0
> ```

Expected Output:

> ```
> link
>    key  keyIndex
> 0    4         8
> 1    2         4
> 2    0         0
> ```

I Tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# prepare dummy data
mapFull = pd.DataFrame()
mapFull['val'] = list(range(12,40,3))

mapSubset = mapFull[mapFull.val % 2 == 0]
mapSubset['key'] = list(range(len(mapSubset)))

link = pd.DataFrame()
link['key'] = [4, 2, 0]

# fill 'keyIndex' values into "link" DataFrame
# try No. 1:
# link['keyIndex'] = mapSubset.index[mapSubset.loc[:, 'key'] == link.loc[:, 'key']]
# --> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

# try No. 2:
link['keyIndex'] = 9999
for pos in range(len(link)):
    ii = mapSubset.index[mapSubset.loc[:,'key'] == link.loc[pos,'key']][0]
    link.loc[pos,'keyIndex'] = ii
```

Try No. 1 resulted in

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

I technically succeeded with 'try No. 2' although that's an ugly workaround.

Furthermore

> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead

is raised for `mapSubset['key'] = list(range(len(mapSubset)))`.

How can I avoid the error messages?
How can the expected result be achieved in a nicer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create the `dict` them map it back

```
link['Keyindex'] = link['key'].map(dict(zip(mapSubset.key,mapSubset.index)))
link
Out[12]: 
   key  Keyindex
0    4         8
1    2         4
2    0         0
```

Comment: Thank you!
Why do you use mapSubset.key and not mapSubset['key']? When do you use which?